# Python CSV reader makes lists inside a list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of urls in a csv file and I need to run them in `for eachUrl in final_url:` but I keep getting a traceback error because I find out that when I print the urls from the below code, it is also printing out `['https://www.anyurl.com']` and not just the url. I have tried to run a loop to replace the `[' ']` but I get the traceback error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`. How do I open the csv and just pull out the URL's and put them into a list without putting them into a list inside another list?

```
import csv
with open('urls_for_BrightScope_Form5500s.csv', 'r') as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r)
    for row in reader:
        final_urls.append(row)
        print(len(final_urls))

Output from final_url list: ['https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/372254/Merritt-Brothers-Lumber-Company/377291/Merritt-Brothers-Lumber-Co-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'], ['https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/255132/Merritt-Club-Management-Inc/259235/Merritt-Club-Management-Inc-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan-And-Trust/'], ['https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/404751/Merritt-Equipment-Co/410055/Merritt-Equipment-Co-401K-Profit-Sharing-Plan/'], ['https://www.brightscope.com/401k-rating/256405/Merritt-Hospitality-Llc/260527/Merritt-Hospitality-401K-Plan/']
```

Comment: A CSV file contains rows and each row contains cells. So yes, each row is a list of cells. Now, since your row is just `['https://www.anyurl.com']`, i.e. it has only one cell, I would say that this is not really a CSV file at all. Why are you reading it as if it was CSV?

Comment: This is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is your `final_urls`? And it would be also good if you can provide us an excerpt from your csv file.

Comment: @kamikaze can u post contents of urls_for_BrightScope_Form5500s or some sample data.

Comment: @Tanmayjain I added output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have only one url in a line, you can also just use line reading, e.g.:

```
with open('urls_for_BrightScope_Form5500s.csv', 'r') as fr:
    final_urls = [url.strip() for url in fr]
```

Comment: lol almost word for word exactly the same answer as mine :D great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input file (`urls_for_BrightScope_Form5500s.csv`) is just a plain text file with one URL in each line, I'd say you should just read the lines, without any `csv` library:

```
with open('urls_for_BrightScope_Form5500s.csv', 'rt') as f:
    final_urls = [line.strip() for line in f]
```